# Optimising SQL sub query in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have the sql using Oracle SQL Developer below that works, but I am concerned about performance over a larger live database.

Please excuse all the join tables, this is showing the connections to the _aud table and revision_table that keeps the audit history.

```
select cust.forename, cust.surname
from customer cust
join section_details sd on cust.section = sd.section
where
-- this value is substituted programatically
sd.type = 5 and
(
  (select max(rt.timestamp)
  from
  customer cust_tmp1
  join section_details sd on cust_tmp1.section = sd.section
  join measure msr on sd.measure = msr.id
  join measure_aud msr_a on msr.id = msr_a.id
  join revision_table rt on msr_a.rev = rt.id
  where
  cust_tmp1.id = cust.id and msr.measure = 'Last Contact Date')
> 
  (select max(rt.timestamp)
  from
  customer cust_tmp2
  join section_details sd on cust_tmp2.section = sd.section
  join measure msr on sd.measure = msr.id
  join measure_aud msr_a on msr.id = msr_a.id
  join revision_table rt on msr_a.rev = rt.id
  where
  cust_tmp2.id = cust.id and  msr.measure = 'Last Order Date')
);
```

In short I only want to retrieve the customer details if the 'Last Contact Date' is more recent than the 'Last Order Date'.  I end up checking the max(timestamp) from one select is greater than the max(timestamp) from the other select.

It all works fine and I get the results I am expecting.

Each side of the timestamp comparison is duplicated apart from the msr.measure = 'Last Contact Date' or 'Last Order Date'.

I have tried a few alternatives that never actually worked as they resulted in multi level nested sub queries and I couldn't pass in the outer cust record.

Any further ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I have tagged with oracle11g and updated my question.  Thanks for the responses I shall try them both shortly if I can or first thing tomorrow and update here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried the solutions posted here and they all seem to work, many thanks for the responses - I hadn't investigated the having clause before.

I added any required indexes and ran explain plans on all the options, my original query had the lowest cost.  So I think I will use that option moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need all those joins?

The same query with different WHERE-conditions usually translates to a CASE:

```
select cust.forename, cust.surname
from customer cust
where
  -- this value is substituted programatically
   sd.type = 5 
and exists
 ( select *
   from
   customer cust_tmp1
   join section_details sd on cust_tmp1.section = sd.section
   join measure msr on sd.measure = msr.id
   join measure_aud msr_a on msr.id = msr_a.id
   join revision_table rt on msr_a.rev = rt.id
   where cust_tmp1.id = cust.id

   having max(case when msr.measure = 'Last Contact Date' then rt.timestamp end)
        > max(case when msr.measure = 'Last Order Date'   then rt.timestamp end)
 )
```

Or simplified removing the subqueries:

```
select cust.forename, cust.surname
from customer cust
join section_details sd on cust_tmp1.section = sd.section
join measure msr on sd.measure = msr.id
join measure_aud msr_a on msr.id = msr_a.id
join revision_table rt on msr_a.rev = rt.id
where
  -- this value is substituted programatically
   sd.type = 5 
group by cust.forename, cust.surname
having max(case when msr.measure = 'Last Contact Date' then rt.timestamp end)
     > max(case when msr.measure = 'Last Order Date'   then rt.timestamp end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could switch this to an `exists`:

```
exists (select max(rt.timestamp)
        from customer cust_tmp1 join
             section_details sd
             on cust_tmp1.section = sd.section join
             measure msr
             on sd.measure = msr.id join
             measure_aud msr_a
             on msr.id = msr_a.id join
             revision_table rt
             on msr_a.rev = rt.id
        where cust_tmp1.id = cust.id and
              msr.measure in ( 'Last Contact Date', 'Last Order Date')
        having max(case when msr.measure = 'Last Contact Date' then rt.timestamp end) >
               max(case when msr.mesure = 'Last Order Date' then rt.timestamp end)
       );
```

I'm not sure if there will be a big performance gain.  If you have the right indexes set up in your database, then your original version should be pretty fast and scalable.